# How does nc identify service names

Tags: networking, ports

```
root@nanana:~# nc -zv localhost 5432
Connection to localhost 5432 port [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!
```

How does nc find out that postgres is listening on the port? just by common port numbers and by assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is based only on the port number.

nc usually gets this information from the `/etc/services` file, which (depending on operating system) might contain either the full contents of IANA [Service Names and Port Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) registry, or a small selection of common ARPANET-era ports, or a mix of both.

(Depending on OS, this file is usually not read directly but rather through getservent() and libc's "nsswitch" infrastructure, which may provide additional sources for service names – e.g. NIS/LDAP/Hesiod.)